# Rails XHTML Builder - a(link) tag inside li(list) tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xhtml

I am trying to build an atom feed using the built in XHTML builder as specified in the docs here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper.html

In my entry.content, what I have is this:

```
entry.content type: 'xhtml' do |xhtml| 
  xhtml.li "Shipped to #{order.address} #{link_to order_name, root_url}"
end
```

The above code prints out the raw link tag like `<a href=""></a>` and not a working link in the feed, which is what I need.

I am a novice in generating xhtml using builder. Any help/suggestiions would be appreciated.

Comment: `xhtml.li raw("stuff")` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. The result is same - raw `<a></a>` tag in the content. I need a working link.

Comment: `xhtml.li("Shipped to..."){|x| x << link_to(...) }` ?

Comment: Error - `XmlMarkup cannot mix a text argument with a block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `xhtml.li {|x| x << "#{order.address} - by #{link_to('Home', root_url)}"}`

Thanks @phlip for giving some direction.

Comment: Except now if your order.address contains any funny business, such as `&`, you are not protected. But other than that I'm glad my guess worked!